# Where is the embeddable iFrame code link for the fusion table itself?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

We want to create a display similar to the http://nycstalled.com/ example in which the map visualization floats left with the table (and links to each record) displays to the right.

If I visualize the table as "map" I get options to Configure info window, Configure styles,
Download KML, Download KML link, and "Get embeddable link"

When I visualize as table, these options are not appearing what I need is "Get embeddable link"

I tried Advanced Search and didn't find an answer. Is this a fusion layers issue?

Answer (score 0):

When the table is displayed,'Get Link' is at the upper right next to 'View in Experimental'

Comment: Thanks, Dick. However, Get Link didn't provide something that could be embedded. Rod Chesney's notes that you can get iFrame embeddable code in the experimental UI from the "Rows 1" tab select tools > Publish to embed up to 500 rows. However, I need to embed more than 1,000 rows of for an intermodal directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an embeddable version of a table visualization with the Experimental UI. Click the Experimental link in the upper right corner. From the "Rows 1" tab select Tools > Publish, which will give you the embed link for a [table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) holding up to 500 rows.

Comment: Thanks, Rod, that did it. Is there any way to embed more than 1,000 rows?